# how to get previous 11 month names from sysdate using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

how to get previous 11 month names from sysdate using oracle

i tried like , iam getting month names between some dates

```
select add_months (trunc (to_date('10/18/2007','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM'), 1*Level -1)
Month   FROM Dual
CONNECT BY Level <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date('11/17/2008','MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date('10/18/2007','MM/DD/YYYY')) + 1
order by month
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i need to get last 11 month names from sysdate .example:sysdate=24-oct-2016 , last 11 months names sep-2016,aug-2016,july-2016...like that

Comment: What is wrong with the query you have?

Comment: that printing the month names between dates

Comment: ... and that's incorrect because...?

Comment: Is your actual question "How to substract 11 months from a date"?

Comment: Are you looking for the [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) method to format a `date`?

Comment: i need to get last 11 month names from sysdate .example:sysdate=24-oct-2016 , last 11 months names sep-2016,aug-2016,july-2016...like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need something like that:

```
select to_char(add_months (to_date('10/18/2007','MM/DD/YYYY'), -1* Level), 'Mon-YYYY')
Month   
FROM Dual
CONNECT BY Level <= 11
order by month
```

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN USE THIS:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1*LEVEL  ),'MON') MONTH_NAME
    FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL  <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(   TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')  , ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-11))
 ORDER BY LEVEL
```